# GList issues (GTK+,C)

Tags: c, list, gtk, glib

I'm having a lot of trouble while saving strings into a glist. When I add a new string, all the previous elements disappear, when I print the whole list with the "FOR" it just appear the last one that I add, in the other spaces in the list is just garbage, like this:

OUTPUT pressing the button 15

```
guardo el elemento:"15"
numero: "15"
```

OUTPUT pressing the button 11

```
guardo el elemento:"11"
numero: ""
numero: "11"
```

OUTPUT pressing the button 10

```
guardo el elemento:"10" 
numero: ""
numero: ""
numero: "10"
```

OUTPUT pressing button 6

```
guardo el elemento:"6"
numero: ""
numero: ""
numero: "0�"
numero: "6"
```

My list is declared in the next structure

```
typedef struct widgets {
  ...
  GList *LISTA;

}WIDGETS;
```

And initialized in main

```
gint main(gint argc,gchar *argv[])
{
 ...
  WIDGETS *boton;
  // 1.- Inicializar el ambiente
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
  boton = malloc(sizeof(WIDGETS));
  boton->tipojuego=1;
  boton->numMov=0;
  boton->bandera=2;
  g_timeout_add(1000,tiempo,boton);
  boton->LISTA=NULL;

...
}
```

The function that saves and print the list elements is ("elementos" points to the same as boton) :

```
void movimientos(GtkWidget *widget,gpointer info)
{
  WIDGETS *elementos=(WIDGETS*)info;

  gchar *str;
  gpointer infor;
  gint i;

  //str=malloc(3*sizeof(char));
  str=gtk_widget_get_name(widget);
  g_print("guardo el elemento:\"%s\" \n",str);

  elementos->LISTA=g_list_append(elementos->LISTA, str); 
  // g_print("Ya se guardo %s",(gchar *)g_list_last(elementos->LISTA)->data);

  for(i=0;i<g_list_length(elementos->LISTA);i++)
    {
      infor=g_list_nth_data(elementos->LISTA,i);

    str=(gchar *)infor;
    g_print("\nnumero: \"%s\"",str);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why `str=malloc()` is commented out here. The pointer will become invalid once the widget is destroyed

Comment: Also the main description of your problem ("all elements disappear when I add another element") isn't true either judging by the output :)

Answer (score 2):

you should not be using `malloc` with GLib: use `g_new()` or `g_new0()`. you also should initialize your `boton` structure first, especially considering that you're passing it around to other functions; don't interleave initialization with assignments and function calls.

the main issue is that `gtk_widget_get_name()` returns a const string, so if the widget goes away, the returned string will contain garbage. you either need to connect to the `GtkWidget::destroy` signal and remove the element from the list, or you'll have to copy the string returned by `gtk_widget_get_name()` before adding it to the list (and then remember to free the contents of the list, as well as the list).

Then there's the issue that your loop on the list is a very inefficient way to loop on a GList:

You ask the list for its length at each iteration, which means iterating over the list each time; then you use `g_list_nth_data()` which will iterate over the list until it reaches the index. a doubly linked list is *not* an array, and yet you are using the former as it were the latter. a proper way to iterate over a list is:

```
GList *l = elementos->LISTA;
for (l = list; l != NULL; l = l->next) {
    const char *str = l->data;

    // ...
}
```

as side notes on the quality and style of your C programming: don't mix lower case (`boton`, `elementos`) and upper case (`WIDGETS`, `LISTA`) in that way (stick to one case), and you're casting way to much (`gpointer` is a typedef to `void *` and gets implicitly cast by C).

after all this, though, I still fail to understand that the issue is, since you don't give enough context for an accurate reply. it seems you're not well versed with C, and that leads me to think that you should probably be using GTK+ with a higher level language before trying your hand with the C API.